# Nextjs, Vercel | GET https://registry.npmjs.org/next/-/next-13.5.0.tgz - Not found

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js, yarnpkg, vercel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tZdn.png)

error: next@https://registry.npmjs.org/next/-/next-13.5.0.tgz' is not in this registry

build is failing on vercel deployment. it was working fine a few minutes ago, all the deployements were success. I made no change. Now none of the deployments are succeeding. All ending with the same error.

Only happening while deployment, build working fine on local.

node
- v19.0.1

I tried to change build method in Vercel, to yarn build, but still the same error

error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/next/-/next-13.5.0.tgz: Request failed "404 Not Found"".

Comment: same issue with npx create-next-app

Answer (score 1):

[image: err]

Also, it's not working locally. It might be a package repository problem.

I just updated the node version, but no use

PS: Try now, It is fixed. I've successfully created a project.

Answer (score 1):

The [13.5.0 version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next/v/13.5.0) has been released and for some reason has been removed immediately.
Now [13.5.1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next/v/13.5.1) is out. You can install it without issues. run `npx create-next-app@latest`

Answer (score 0):

it also happened to me this afternoon for some reasons. I suspect there might be an issue with the server